# Orekit Import Error in Python Mac OS 10.11.6 El Capitan issue?

Tags: python, java

I tried to download the orekit for python package. Originally, I did try pip install, but it didn't work. I had to install jcc, change my paths, and change my Python version from 3.6 to 2.7. When I finally got that working I did conda install (conda install -c http://conda.anaconda.org/ssc orekit) and the terminal did say it successfully downloaded.

As soon as I tried to import orekit in Jupyter Notebooks I received the following error message.

Code: 
import orekit 
orekit.initVM()

Error: 
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last) 
 in () 
----> 1 import orekit 
      2 orekit.initVM()

/Users/name/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/orekit/**init**.py in () 
      1 
----> 2 import os, _orekit 
      3 
      4 **dir** = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(**file**)) 
      5

ImportError: dlopen(/Users/name/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/orekit/_orekit.so, 2): Library not loaded: @rpath/libjava.dylib 
  Referenced from: /Users/name/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/orekit/_orekit.so 
  Reason: image not found

From my internet searching it seems like it may be a dylib issue with the version I have of Mac (El Capitan 10.11.6). I cannot change my Mac version as it is a work computer. I have spent many hours unsuccessfully googling any and all help is appreciated.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this question is not even remotely related to Elementary OS.

Comment: @AxelAdvento: Where should I post it?

Answer (score 0):

It is very likely that orekit cannot find the java. New versions of the conda package has been created on conda-forge that automatically sets JCC_JDK to the conda-supplied jdk that is automatically installed as a dependency.

See instruction for installation on:
https://github.com/conda-forge/orekit-feedstock